# does jqgrid support a multiple checkbox list for editing

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I am [playing around with jqgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and I want to edit a row entry. One of the cells is a list so I want some sort of multiselect editor inside a cell.  i dont see support for a cell edit where i can choose multiple entries from a list. select (either multiselect list or even better a dropdown of checkboxes)

is there any support for something like this?? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0fb79d.htm

[image]

```
jQuery("#grid_id").setGridParam({multiselect:true}).showCol('cb');
```

Comment: i dont want multiselect rows. I want an editor in a cell that will allow me to select multiple entries to represent a list.

Comment: Check out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825000/jqgrid-multi-checkbox-custom-edittype-solution ... it looks like "gsiler" has created a "multi-checkbox form element" and used it as a custom edit-type.

Answer (score 3):

Working example:

> { name: "Id_ListaMultiple",
>   index:"Id_ListaMultiple",editable:true,edittype:"custom",editoptions:{custom_element:multiCheckElem,
>   custom_value:multiCheckVal,list:"2:Reposición;1:Solicitud Inicial"}},

```
function multiCheckElem(values, optio) {
    var id = optio.id;
    var ctl = '<div id="'+ id + '" class="checklist">';
    var ckboxAry = optio.list.split(';');
    var aValues = [];
    if (values && values.length)
    {
        aValues = values.split(",");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < ckboxAry.length; i++)
    {
        var item = ckboxAry[i].split(':');
        ctl += '<input type="checkbox" ';

        if (aValues.indexOf(item[0]) != -1)
        {
            ctl += 'checked="checked" ';
        }
        ctl += 'value="' + item[0] + '"> ' + item[1] + '</input><br/>';
    }
    return ctl + '</div>';
}

function multiCheckVal(elem, action, val) {
    var items = '';
    if (action == 'get') // submitted
    {

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", elem).each(function (i, e)
        {
            if (items) items += ","
            items += e.value;
        });

    }
    else // launched
    {

    }
    return items;
}
```

Regards Henry

Comment: The problem here is how can I get the values salved before and show it checked when my form opens in edit action??