# jqgrid multiselect edit form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need a form structure to read from JSON, put the values in a multiselect field in edit form mode(not inline), and let the user set the values for the ones he selected.
I dont know if its possible.

I did this and worked fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4985705/1052077
But I still need to associate a value to each of the selected items in the second list, like and input so the user can select the number he wants.
Like "physics - 4" and then grab that number(4) to save server side.

I wanted something like this http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser
But the ones I found were only accepting the columns values, not any kind of source value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [multiselect widget](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) directly without the [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#column_chooser). The last version of the widget you can find on the [github](https://github.com/michael/multiselect/).

Comment: Oleg, ur a savior! lol Thank you very much! Will try the widget directly and post a response here!

Comment: @Mah: Sorry, Mah, but the stackoverflow is not the place where somebody do any job for you. The code on the github contains the html page with [the demo page](https://github.com/michael/multiselect/blob/master/index.html). You can [download](https://github.com/michael/multiselect/zipball/master) the full source code with the demo and modify it how you as want.

Comment: Oleg, I know stackoverflow isnt about that. And I really dont want somebody "doing my job" cause Im only here to learn. About the widget, it didnt solved my problem since I want to insert an input box inside the widget to associate every selected option with a particular value and sent it to a server. But, as I seem to be looking for an easy job or something, Ill try to find that again in the widget code by myself. Im sorry for troubling you or something.