# In jqGrid, is there anyway to use Ajax to get data for your custom_element?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am doing something [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825000/jqgrid-multi-checkbox-custom-edittype-solution) where I have a list of checkboxes as a custom edit control.  The difference is that I want to get my list from the server (not hard coded on the client with **Check1, Check2, Check3**.

Is there any way to do this either in the column setup or in the **custom_element** function?

It seems like I need something similar to the **dataUrl** property that you use for select items but that seems to only apply to select items (not custom ones).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any `list` option (to be exactly `editoptions`) during the grid initialization and then overwrite the value with the real data loaded from the server:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        {name:'MyMultiCheck',edittype:'custom',
         editoptions:{custom_element:MultiCheckElem,
                      custom_value:MultiCheckVal,list:''}
        }
        ...
    ]
    ...
});
$.ajax({
    url:"getMultiCheckList",
    // any other parameters like dataType:'json',
    // type: 'POST' (default type is 'GET') which depend on the server
    success: function(data){
        // the code here depend on the format of data returned from the server
        // in the simplest situation we have as data already the comma-separated
        // string which we need as a value for the list parameter so we can do
        jQuery("#list").setColProp('MyMultiCheck',{editoptions:{list:data}});
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for all your help.  This is very close to the right answer but one think i noticed is that if you only set List, it drops the custom_element and custom)_value settings so you have to include those options (just repeat whats in initialization) as well to get it to work.